# Ошибки в python

Tags: python

Как продолжить выполнение кода, не смотря на ошибку?

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    try:
        a = int("fsdfs")
    except:
        continue

    print(i)
```

Comment: Так у вас итак рабочий код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, код рабочий. Если вопрос в том "как сделать так, чтобы выполнялась команда print(i)?", то нужно в блоке except убрать continue, т.к. после выполнения этой строчки начинается следующая итерация цикла.